# How to switch to another window when Ctrl + B does not work for tmux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tmux, linux-terminal

As we all know tmux is quite nice tool, but there are some scenarios that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> cannot be used.

For example, when I sshd to server A and now I connect to A's tmux pty. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is captured by server A.

Then I ssh to server B from server A and **tmux is already running on Server B**. This time, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> only works for server A and cannot be used by server B. So, if I want to switch window for server B, what should I do then?

Answer (score 2):

You can still use <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd>, but you need to repeat it to send to the nested tmux.

A better option would be to use different prefixes. For example the nested tmux could have:

```
set-option -g prefix C-a
```

in its `tmux.conf`, then <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> will be its prefix.